# closing all open workbooks without saving and then open an another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'am looking for the VBA-code for closing all open workbooks without saving and then open an another workbook.

Nows anybody the correct VBA-code?

I have now the follow code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WB As Workbook

For Each WB In Workbooks
    If Not (WB Is ActiveWorkbook) Then WB.Close
Next

End Sub
```

This one i haven't tried jet. I try to make a macro dat starts every day one the same time and closed all workbooks. Then opens workbooks and update the data.

Comment: just slight amendment to your code for it to NOT save changes: `WB.Close savechanges:=False`

Answer (score 2):

I have adjust WB.Close savechanges:=False to the VBA-code and its works perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using macro is not a good way to do this.
Check this out.
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/04/25/close-all-files-in-excel-2013/

Or you could do this using cmd command like

```
taskkill /IM excel.exe /F
start excel.exe
```

or making a batch file or a vbscript doing the same.

Comment: with all due respect: how is killing excel through taskkill altogether better than closing all workbooks??

Comment: Using taskkill without `/F` option will let you save unsaved documents with it's default asking dialog and the reason why I put `/F` is only beacuse assuming that you've already saved it all.
Sometimes, you can have multiple excel instances that acts weird on closing event especially when opening documents with web browser's 'open' function.
This taskkill will bypass such headaches and make fresh start with new excel.

Comment: the question is how to do it in VBA, and not whats the best way to grow plants...